# How to do RDS IAM Authentication with Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I want my django application connect to RDS postgres using IAM authentication. That means the db password expires every 15min and should be re-generated. The problem is how can I change the database password in the runtime? Or should I update my database URL environment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We implemented a package for this functionality and published to PyPi. You can check it here https://github.com/labd/django-iam-dbauth

But in principle here are the steps:

First [enable IAM Authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Enabling.html).

Then [add the policy and attach it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html) to the role or user that connects to the DB.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "rds-db:connect"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-2:1234567890:dbuser:db-ABCDEFGHIJKL01234/db_userx"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Then create a user on your AWS postgres and grant `rds_iam` role to it:

```
CREATE USER db_userx WITH LOGIN; 
GRANT rds_iam TO db_userx;
```

For Django, you need a custom backend to allow generating credentials on the fly.

Create a package such as `your.package.postgresql` with a `base.py` in it

```
import boto3
from django.db.backends.postgresql import base

class DatabaseWrapper(base.DatabaseWrapper):
    def get_connection_params(self):
        params = super().get_connection_params()
        rds_client = boto3.client("rds")
        params["password"] = rds_client.generate_db_auth_token(
            DBHostname=params.get("host", "localhost"),
            Port=params.get("port", 5432),
            DBUsername=params.get("user") or getpass.getuser(),
        )

        return params
```

Then use a settings like:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "HOST": "<hostname>",
        "USER": "<user>",
        "PORT": 5432,
        "ENGINE": "your.package.postgresql"
    }
}
```

Comment: This your.package.postgresql approach is clean, and works -- but only for 15 minutes. After that, the auth token expires and subsequent connections fail. I've tried your package on GitHub but get
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "db_userx"`
Will continue looking...

Comment: Old comment, but for anyone in the future: I believe you should be able to use the Django database config for [CONN_MAX_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#conn-max-age). Getting ready to convert to IAM authentication in one of my projects and I believe that should force a reconnection