# How to reconnect to RDS psql DB in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, boto3, amazon-rds

I have recently wrote a small django app which connects to the external database (AWS RDS psql instance). Authentication is done using IAM role of EC2 instance (server). Things work OK for about 15-20min. After this time the error I'm getting is:

```
Exception Value: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "db_user_name"
```

My guess is that a token generated by boto3 expires and I loose the connection. Below shows how the token is obtained.

```
client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=REGION)
password = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=DB_HOST, Port=DB_PORT, DBUsername=DB_USER, Region=REGION)
```

If this is the case, how can I force django to reconnect to the DB with a fresh token? The error originates in the django core. At the moment I work only with Django native admin panel.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html), IAM-based RDS token lifetime is 15 minutes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865837/how-to-do-rds-iam-authentication-with-django) question has decent approach in answers to fix it. Did not try it in practice yet though. You can also try to use persistent connections [by setting CONN_MAX_AGE to None](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-CONN_MAX_AGE) if that makes sense in your environment.